# html file fails once loaded

Tags: html, error, file-upload

I'm encountering an error that i can't figure out.
I have some html files that I open perfectly withthe browser (falkon) on my pc. But, once i upload them to the website, they give me Internl Server Error.
I have tried the following:

a- verify the link is correct
b- open the file from the parent directory
c- upload the file again with filezilla
d- upload the file again with the website utility
e- change the file name

note that some of the files from the same batch and from the same directory work fine and all the files work if I open them on the pc.

any suggestion?

Comment: `.html` files that cause a 500 series error would point to a misconfiguration of the server, I would think. It might be helpful to post screenshots of the files in the folder on the web server, and a screenshot of the browser with the URL plus the error message.

Comment: what's puzzling is that in the same folder I have html files I've uploaded at the same time and the same way which work fine.

Comment: Check file permissions, too. And if you are able, check server logs to get the error details.

Comment: An "internal server error" is very generic.  That is your web server saying "something went wrong".   To diagnose the problem we would need more information such as entries from the webservers error log which usually has more information about what the problem actually is.

Comment: Ok, let me try to get the log, be patient, I'm a total beginner.

Comment: permission is 644 on all files

Comment: where would i find the webserver error log?

Comment: I think it mut have something to do with the files themselves. I get the same error whether I open them in the parent directory or even if I move them to another directory. What may cause a file to behave differently once uploaded (I've uploaded them in different ways and even renamed them to test for errors)?

Comment: here's the link to one of the failing archives: http://scriptanarchy.com/tele/alfred_hitchcock_hour_magic_shop.html

Comment: Just looked at that archive and yep, gonna need the logs to make sense of this one. I suggest you look through your hosting provider's help center to see where they store the error logs.

Comment: @black-clover Try changing the file permission to `0755` using `chmod` or the FTP program you're using (usually right-click -> Properties will display that option). If you have any server-side scripting in the documents, such as PHP, you'll need to change the file extension as well to the corresponding language (.e.g., `.html` -> `.php`). Your local server and OS, especially Windows, may not require these.

Comment: Dan: I changed the permission to 0755 and now when I try to open the archive it sends me back to the main page.

Comment: Maximilian: There are no errors reported in the logs.

Comment: @black-clover Archive? What type of files are you trying to serve, and what language are they written in? Btw, please use `@username` (without any spaces) to direct your comments  to users, otherwise they won't be notified of them.

Comment: @dan they are html archives (you can try the link above). like I said, I can open them in m pc, but once loaded some of them give me an error. The link is correct, I get the error even when I try to open them in the parent dir.

Comment: here is the comment to a file that works: http://scriptanarchy.com/tele/10_Things_I_Hate_About_You_1x01_-_Pilot.html for comparison.

Comment: @black-clover What do you mean by "HTML archive"? Archives are typically compressed or packaged files, such as a `.zip`. What file extension are they (right-click and get Properties on them), and do they contain PHP or another scripting language? If they're something other than plain HTML, you'll need to configure your server to serve them (e.g., by adding a `mime` type or script-alias). Links to files that aren't being served are not helpful...because they're not being served and we can't see them. You should also check your `error` logs.

Comment: @dan I mean a HTML file (a pdf converted to HTML). you can check the links: http://scriptanarchy.com/tele/alfred_hitchcock_hour_magic_shop.html (error) http://scriptanarchy.com/tele/10_Things_I_Hate_About_You_1x01_-_Pilot.html (works). Both were converted form pdf to html with the same ap, and I can open both with falkon on my pc, but once uploaded, the first one does not work. That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @black-clover See my comment above, and others stating that you need to check your server's error logs to see what the issues are. Contact your web hosting service's technical support or search their support docs to find out where the error docs are located. We're unable to help you further here. Good luck.

Comment: As I said above, the logs show no errors.